# Having unique Redis instances pushing to central Redis?

Tags: database, redis

Let's say that I have a few Redis instances (we can call them A, B and C), all with unique data and unable to communicate with each other.  I'd like them to push their data to a 'master' instance (let's call it Maestro).

Is there any way to doing this automatically with Redis itself, or would I have to write my own (simple) tool to do this?

Redis replication doesn't seem fit for this purpose.

The simplest way to do this I've come up with so far is to write a small client that runs on each node that would simply run every x seconds:

```
MIGRATE Maestro 6739 MyKey
```

**Edit**: turns out that this isn't a good way to do it, since the key can't exist in the destination database.

While this is an fairly simple solution, my question is:
Am I missing out on some Redis configuration to do this automatically (or in a better way)?

Answer (score 0):

Redis is designed to work in the other way, like many other databases: data are written on the master, and replicated on slaves.
The `slaveof` command cannot be used to achieve what you are looking for, as it does not allow a node to be the slave of most than one -- that is to say the data to be replicated from several node on a unique one.